# WHO IS THE SUBJECT? 政府には or 私たちから

Tags: meaning

> 政府には、私たちから取る税金の使い方をもっとしっかり_____
>
> - 1 考えられます
> - 2 考えてあげたいです
> - 3 考えてもらいたいです
> - 4 考えてくれます

The main question I have is WHO IS THE SUBJECT?  I thought that 私たち is the subject because it says から = FROM.  Hence I chose option 2, BUT IT WAS WRONG. The correct answer is 3.  So I ask again WHY is 政府 the subject?  It has a に in it, meaning towards.

Answer (score 4):

The subject of the main clause is neither 私たち nor 政府, but "implicit I" (singular). The subject of a "-tai" sentence is normally "I", and it is normally omitted.

- この映画を見たいです。
  **I** want to watch the movie.
  <sub>(私は is almost always omitted)</sub>
- この映画を見てもらいたいです。
  **I** want [someone] to watch the movie.
- 彼に(は)この映画を見てもらいたいです。
  **I** want him to watch the movie.
- 政府に(は)Xをもっと考えてもらいたいです。
  **I** want the government to think more about X.
- 政府に(は)私たちからとる税金の使い方をもっと考えてもらいたいです。
  **I** want the government to think more about how they spend the tax they take from us.

In all the five examples above, the implicit **subject** is "I". If you're already confused by the second or the third sentence above, please reread your textbook and review how to use もらう and に together. Also note that the **topic** of the original sentence is 政府 (because it's explicitly marked with は), but topic and subject are different concepts in Japanese.

税金の使い方を考えてあげたいです means "I want to think how to spend taxes *(for someone's sake / on behalf of someone)*". It's not an ungrammatical sentence, but only a very arrogant person who believes he is greater than the government itself would say something like this.